# OpenGl SOIL linking to visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, opengl, soil

I have a problem with linking SOIL to my OpenGL project so I'm asking you if one can show me how to link it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Rightclick on the project -> Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories -> Add Library Path
(I have version in another language so the names could be a little different)

Then you write into your Programm `#pragma comment(lib,"NAMEOFLIB")`

Comment: I know, how to link onter libraries, but SOL doesn't have the .lib file. It has the .a file.

Comment: that sounds stupid but i think that i just changed the .a to a .lib and it worked

Comment: you mean to rename the file? But it gives me and error: cannot open libSOIL.lib

Comment: i found a working version of the file on my computer and uploaded it: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=CF5ABC1A46725010!440&authkey=!AFhaF3v_sPtuYyo&ithint=file%2clib

Comment: oh thank you soo much. I'll try and tell you if it works

Comment: yes, thanks it worked. I'll tell yo if any of the SOIL functions wont work. Thanks for all